# Compensation in the EU after a delayed flight - In what time frame should compensation be issues?

Tags: air-travel, compensation, delays, ec261

Recently I had a long delay on a flight. As per the [Regulation (EC) No 261/2004 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 11 February 2004](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32004R0261) , this entitles me to compensation by the airline.

Within what time frame should this compensation be delivered? It has now been well over two months since I originally requested the compensation.

For other circumstances, such as for re-routing or downgrading, it appears to stipulate that the reimbursement  should be payed within seven days:

For example, `Right to reimbursement or re-routing` states

```
reimbursement within seven days, ....
```

Furthermore, as I originally intended to use the compensation for my next flight I opted for the 'voucher' option, which was worth 150% of the compensation amount for flights with the same airline. In my interpretation of the following, this does not change anything in relation to the time frame in which the compensation should be given.

> The compensation referred to in paragraph 1 shall be paid in cash, by electronic bank transfer, bank orders or bank cheques or, with the signed agreement of the passenger, in travel vouchers and/or other services.

So, what is the timeframe in which the compensation should be issues?

Comment: Companies may question your right to a compensation. This may lead to a trial. I'm still waiting for my compensation two years later, and it is still pending.

Comment: Has the airline confirmed you are due compensation? The fact you've stated you were given an option of vouchers makes it sound like that have, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Some airlines follow the argumentation that if you accept their offer for an alternative and higher compensation, which you have in this case, the airline is no longer bound to follow the other parts of the EU regulation, like time limits for the refund.

Answer (score 3):

> So, what is the timeframe in which the compensation should be issues?

Irrelevant question. Most airlines will happily ignore what the rules say unless you somehow force them or put pressure on them.

Most airlines will initially just ignore your claim and hope that you will go away quietly. Then they will drag their feet and delay as much as possible. Your best recourse is to constantly call or contact them and insist on your rights and threatening legal action.

There are also professional companies you can hire to collect for you for a percentage of the proceeds. These companies have a strong history of taking every claim to court, so the airlines are more inclined to pay. This may not work for a voucher though.